# How to update data in sqlsrv using PHP

Tags: php, sqlsrv

Hi guys im having difficult time here. i want to update data in sql server by using php but it keeps failing. can anyone help me with this? here are my sample codes i have used. Please guys help me with that i have been assigned to create that and it keeps me failing.im not sure where the problem is. i will be thankfull for your help.

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
        $server = "WIN-2012SRV-BK";
        $user = "sa";
        $pass = "";
        $db = "test";
        $connInfo = array("Database"=>$db, "UID"=>$user, "PWD"=>$pass);
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $connInfo) or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));


        //$id = $_POST['id'];
        //$emp_salary = $_POST['emp_salary'];
        $pin = $_POST['pin'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];

        $sql = "UPDATE [test].[dbo].[subscriptions] ". "SET pin = {$pin} ". 
           "WHERE phone = {$phone}" ;
        //$sqlsrv_select_db('test');
        $retval = sqlsrv_query( $sql, $conn );

        if(! $retval ) {
           die('Could not update data: ');
        }
        echo "Updated data successfully\n";

        mysql_close($conn);
     }else {
        ?>
           <form method = "post" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
              <table width = "400" border =" 0" cellspacing = "0" 
                 cellpadding = "0">

                 <tr>
                    <td width = "100">Phone Number</td>
                    <td><input name = "phone" type = "text" 
                       id = "phone"></td>
                 </tr>

                 <tr>
                    <td width = "100"> </td>
                    <td> </td>
                 </tr>

                 <tr>
                    <td width = "100"> </td>
                    <td>
                       <input name = "update" type = "submit" 
                          id = "update" value = "Update">
                    </td>
                 </tr>

              </table>
           </form>
        <?php
     }
  ?>
```

The error i am getting is

Warning: sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\visionFund\pin-reset.php on line 70
Could not update data:

Comment: When you say "failing", what does that actually mean? _Please be precise_... Do you get an error? Does nothing happen? Do you get a white page in your browser? What do you find in your http servers error log file?

Comment: Sorry for no being clear. This is the error it returns "Warning: sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\visionFund\pin-reset.php on line 70
Could not update data: "

Comment: In general (for future questions), please add additional information to the question, not in comments. There is an `edit` button below your question, _use it_.

Comment: About the specific error message: that helps quite a lot! `sqlsrv_query()` expects the connection as _first_ argument, you hand it over as second. Check the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php

Comment: Oky thank you arkascha let me check that

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the connection string inside the query:

```
$sql = "$connection_string,UPDATE [test].[dbo].[subscriptions] ". "SET pin = {$pin} ". "WHERE phone = {$phone}" ;
```